# How can i write these if statements as a single nested switch

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying to write this if statement here as a switch statement

```
if (value < 2500) {
  paystackFees = value * 0.015;
};
if (paystackFees > 2000) {
  paystackFees = 2000
};
```

Comment: you can't use switch here, because switch can't perform a logic operation (like greater than `<`). However, you can use `else if` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no hard rule whether to use a switch or if-else but I'd prefer to use a switch whenever I’m switching on the value of a single variable having at least two options with constant values to differentiate between. Anyways You can use a switch by simply putting a switch(true) and having your conditions placed as it is.

```
if (value < 2500) {
  paystackFees = value * 0.015;
if (paystackFees > 2000) {
  paystackFees = 2000
};
};
```

With switch:

```
   switch(true) {
      case value < 2500:
        paystackFees = value * 0.015;
        break;
      case value < 1500:
        // If you wish to extend it further
        paystackFees = value * 0.015;
        break;
      default:
        // Have a default value here
        break;
    }

switch(true){
  case payStackFees > 2000:
    payStackFees = 2000;
    break
  case payStackFees > 3500 && payStackFees < 4000
    payStackFees = 3800;
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a switch statement as follows:

```
switch(true){
  case value < 2500: 
    paystackFees = value * 0.015;
    break;
  case paystackFees > 2000: 
    paystackFees = 2000 
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

But it seems a bit problematic as a value can meet both requirements, e.g:

```
2250 < 2500 && 2250 > 2000
```

So the order of your switch cases will determine the ending value of `paystackFees`. You can also omit `break` statements, in that case your result will entirely depend on the very last case.